# A tfel tfel deer rebus

Tags: rebus

See if you can solve the following rebus:

[image]

Given how easily my previous problems have been solved, I am unwiling to give any hints. But maybe one won’t hurt.

Comment: I'm really annoyed at how people edit questions without asking. If you think anyone's made a mistake, post in a comment rather than editing. In the majority of my puzzles, I will make no mistakes. Everything is intended.

Comment: Most of the time, things that *look* like formatting and spelling errors *are* formatting and spelling errors. You can't fault somebody for trying to fulfill their community obligation without knowing your intent in *purposefully* including an error.

Comment: Well - it's happened twice to me and in both cases destroying part of the puzzle. I really think people should ask in the comments beforehand.

Comment: If a puzzle includes something that looks like a mistake, but it's supposed to be a hint, there needs to be something _else_ -- a sort of meta-hint -- to reinforce the fact that it's intentional.

Comment: Perhaps there should be a tag for it, but I often prefer that hints are non-obvious.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My solution:

> Read right to left.

Explanation [EDIT 1 - thanks to Developer107 in the comments]:

> The first two words are "left" (from right to left) in a font that makes them look handwritten. When you go from right to left in the rebus, you get "reed write two left". And when you say that out loud (read it), you get "Read right to left."

Which is clever because:

> The rebus itself tells you how to decipher it.

Old Explanation (Incomplete):

> If you read this right to left you get "reed left left". Which is like "read" and two lefts.

Comment: For some reason it does not feel like this is the complete answer. Work harder, Duncan! Why the different fonts? Why would simply reading it backwards solve the problem? That is too obvious.

Comment: I think it's correct, why don't you?

Comment: Perhaps I have watched too much Poirot.

Comment: Maybe with the slight modification: "write two left" because it is a script font hence more like writing than printing.

Comment: With the help by @HughMeyers comment, I just want to add to your explanation. It is 'reed write(because of script font) 2 left' so that indicates 'Read(reed) right(write) to(2) left' that is the same answer but with a slightly different explanation.

Comment: It may have something to do with "black deer"

Comment: Very nice. It's the right answer :) Now explain the *hint*. Edit: Actually nevermind - autocorrect ruined it. Double edit: Actually, wrong again, the editor of the question ruined it!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Never edit questions without asking!!!!!

Comment: In addition, yes some of the comments here are right. Not every aspect of this puzzle is explained yet, although you have the right answer.

Comment: @QuestionAsker - I'm not getting much else from this. Does it have anything to do with the specific font that's used? Or the bold vs. script writing?

Comment: No no - you got the correct answer, but the explanation for it wasn't quite complete. Some of it is already written here in the comments, like the font, for example (which looks like writing). I also edited back the question to retain the hint, which should be obvious now.

Comment: @QuestionAsker Okay, made some changes. Let me know if that's better!

Comment: Correct. In addition, my hint was about spelling which implied not everything in the rebus is spelt correctly (also to attempt to confuse, since the solver might think of something to do with 'deer')